# Linux Redirect Messages: __strlen_avx2, __mempcpy_avx_unaligned_erms, __strchrnul_avx2

Tags: c, linux, redirect

[image]

I have questions regarding the three redirect messages I got. Just to give some context to my program...

I am using C programming and Linux. I read numbers from a file containing all the words in a dictionary. I extract the words from the file and save them in a string object which consists of 3 things: a dynamically allocated array of characters for the words (the string objects are designed so that I do not need null terminators at the end of the arrays), an integer for the size of the word currently being stored, and an integer for the capacity of the current dynamically allocated array of characters. Each string object itself is stored in a vector, and I have an array of 30 vectors with the index of each vector corresponding to the size of the words. For example, index 2 in my array of vectors has 94 words which means the vector at index 2 contains 94 string objects with each object holding a word of size 2. After storing them in the vectors, I then print them to stdout (you can see the tail end of this), and then print out the size of each vector as well as the total words extracted.

Up until now (I'm a fairly new CS student so bear with me), I ran my code always with valgrind and --leak-check=full. As you can see, I have no memory leaks or errors. However, I became aware of the "-v" I could run my program with as well, and when I do that, I get the three redirect messages:

```
libc.so.6:__strlen_avx2
libc.so.6:__mempcpy_avx_unaligned_erms
libc.so.6:__strchrnul_avx2
```

I have no idea what these mean. I tried trying to figure it out for myself by looking it up online and I couldn't figure it out so I'm wondering what those errors mean. The last thing I'll say is, the first redirect message involves "strlen" which is a string library function in C's string.h library. However, I never use string.h. The whole point of this project was for me to create my own customized string objects and my own library of string functions to work with these string objects. So, assuming that the redirect message is referring to the string.h library function, I have no idea why it's doing that.

I didn't post any code since it's a long project. I'm just looking for answers as to in general what those messages could be referring to.

Comment: Those are different versions of the functions optimized for different x86 instruction sets that are used when the CPU the program is being run on supports them to get better performance than the defaults.

Comment: Hey Shawn, thanks for your assistance. Are you saying then that I made an error somewhere and those messages are informing me of that, or I should just ignore them?

Comment: Ignore the messages.

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind will check the use of library functions too - such as `strlen`, `memcpy`, `strchrnul`.

When you compile with some optimizations enabled or otherwise, then these function calls might be replaced with an optimized version, i.e. here ones optimized for AVX and AVX2. But those functions are doing some dirty tricks that would otherwise be illegal in C, and also hard for `valgrind` to check. So valgrind reditrects the call to `__strlen_avx2` back to `strlen`, so that valgrind can more easily track the specifics. Now, `-v` means only `--verbose` and it shows more information... and for some it might be crucial to know that the actual function `__strlen_avx2` is not called at all, unlike when not run with `valgrind`, but any calls to that would jump to the `strlen` controlled by `valgrind` instead.